# Custom Login System In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I create a customized login system in Laravel.

**This is my controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Front extends Controller
{
    public function register()
    {
        if (Request::isMethod('post')) {
            User::create([
                'name' => Request::get('name'),
                'email' => Request::get('email'),
                'password' => bcrypt(Request::get('password')),
            ]);
        }

        return Redirect::away('login');
    }

    public function authenticate()
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => Request::get('email'), 'password' => Request::get('password')])) {
            return redirect()->intended('checkout');
        } else {
            return view('login', array('title' => 'Welcome', 'description' => '', 'page' => 'home'));
        }
    }

    public function login()
    {
        return view('auth/login', array('page' => 'home'));
    }

    public function checkout()
    {
        return view('/aboutme', array('page' => 'home'));
    }
}
```

**And the routes are:**

```
// Authentication routes...
Route::get('auth/login', 'Front@login');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Front@authenticate');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Front@logout');

// Registration routes...
Route::post('/register', 'Front@register');

Route::get('/checkout', [
    'middleware' => 'auth',
    'uses' => 'Front@checkout'
]);
```

**The error i am getting is:**

> FatalErrorException in Front.php line 12: Class
>   'App\Http\Controllers\Request' not found

Comment: You can also override Authentication Trait methods like postLogin(), postRegister() etc instead of creating it from scratch.
use Illuminate\Http\Request; should fix the fatal error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import Request. Add this to the top of your controller:

```
use Request;
```

By the way you will need to do this for the `Redirect` facade as well.

Your imports should look like this:

```
use Auth;
use Request;
use Redirect;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following as it seems like you are not using Request specific namespace in your `Front Controller`:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```